# How can I combine two tables and merge fields?

Tags: ms-access

Apologies is this is an incredibly obvious question but I'm new to access and have learned it over the past week through a rather daunting project.

Basically I am in the process of designing a database to track everything the company does: people it knows, things it does, meetings it holds, etc.

I think I've structured it pretty well, but what I would like is an "activity" table. Because the activities are diverse, they are all in multiple tables (events, meetings, enquiries, etc), but they all have a sort of general description field. Is there some way to make a table or form that will pull in all of that data and sort of lay it out as:

Date - Type - Description.

Type would be based on where it came from, so if the meetings table was the source of the information, then it would be typed as meeting.

I realise a simpler way to do this would have been to have an activities table with categories as breaking it up seems easier than combining it, but the number of fields that would mean having on one table made that seem impossible to run.

This seems like something that should be simple, but I'm struggling.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered a history table and data macros http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg435977(v=office.14).aspx? Alternatively, a UNION query may suit. It depends on whether you need to edit etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is rather broad, we may need some additional information. Please edit your question and include your tables structure, and any other attempts you've made to solve your problem. Also, I recommend you get a good book or find a good tutorial on SQL (the language, not the product ;) )

Comment: @Fionnuala The UNION query was perfect, thank you! I thought I'd examined queries fully, but apparently not, and after some fiddling I've sorted it. Thanks a lot!